# Cannot find sensor data in /sys/class/input or getevent in android using adb

Tags: android, events, adb, android-sensors

I am trying to capture the events generated by accelerometer and gyroscope sensors and put them into a log file. But I am not able to see any events for them. Only 6 events are being shown, but none is for these sensors.
[image]

getevent is showing these values. I also checked inside sys/class/input which shows the same thing
[image]

The /sys/class don't have any sensors directory as such for my mobile.
So where can I look for the sensor data in sysfs or devfs?

Comment: please do not post text as images

Answer (score 0):

The old architecture where all separate sensors were connected directly to the main AP (application processor) and therefore had separate device drivers has been extremely power inefficient (the AP had to be awake in order to receive the sensor events). In many newer devices it has been replaced with the new architecture where sensors are connected to the *[SensorHub](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-stack.html)* instead which manages the event queues now.

Comment: My device has snapdragon 800 and it has a separate aDSP chip to process sensor data [link](https://assets.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-77a3617e0142bafc7844fe11ffd3e5ab-c?convert_to_webp=true) . Is there any way I could read this data directly when the events are generated?